# Finding a path without the file name

Tags: ruby, path

I'm attempting to create a a program that will give the full path to a file. This can be done with `File.absolute_path`, but it also adds the file name to the path. For example,

```
def test
  path = File.absolute_path("test.rb")
  puts path
end
#=> C:/users/james/myscripts/test/test.rb
```

I need to exclude the last part `/test.rb` so that the path would only contain: `C:/users/james/myscripts/test`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I am not sure how you can get `C:/users/james/myscripts/test/test.rb` as the absolute path of `"test.txt"`.

Comment: @sawa Lol, well that's my bad..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `File.absolute_path("test.txt")` gives the absolute path, and you want the directory of it, then that means that you just want the current directory. That is given by:

```
Dir.pwd
```

Comment: This brought a smile to my face.

Answer (score 5):

[`File.dirname`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/File.html#method-c-dirname) will return the directory part of the path:

```
File.dirname(File.absolute_path("test.txt"))
# => C:/users/james/myscripts/test
```